# How can I avoid a SplitPane to resize one of the panes when the window resizes?

Tags: resize, javafx-2

I want to resize the pane only manually dragging the splitter with the mouse.
But when the window is resized,  I would like that pane to keep the exact size that I chose.  Allowing the other pane to change size freely.

Do you think of any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should use `SplitPane.setResizableWithParent` static method.

```
        SplitPane root = new SplitPane();

        final Pane paneFixed = new StackPane();
        paneFixed.getChildren().add(new Text("fixed"));

        SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(paneFixed, Boolean.FALSE);

        Pane paneFree = new StackPane();
        paneFree.getChildren().add(new Text("free"));

        root.getItems().addAll(paneFree, paneFixed);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 200));
        stage.show();
```

Comment: Answered my own question. Yes, you can set this in FXML: `SplitPane.resizableWithParent="false"` on the child control.

Comment: I had problems with SplitPane when window was resizing , `SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(node, Boolean.FALSE);`  solved them !!