# JavaFX Scenebuilder: Is it possible to disable the resizing of the SplitPane divider?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

Is it possible to disable automatic resizing/placement of the divider of a SplitPane when resizing the entire frame? In other words, I only want it to automatically move the divider only to shrink (when the application's frame is too small) or if the user manually moves the divider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what your are looking for : [How can I avoid a SplitPane to resize one of the panes when the window resizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000098/how-can-i-avoid-a-splitpane-to-resize-one-of-the-panes-when-the-window-resizes)

and from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#setResizableWithParent-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Boolean-)